# Replace entire DOM (page) with response from $http in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, stripe-payments

I have HTML AngualrJS application which works as follow:

1. User types payment info on the form, form does not have action attribute set
2. user clicks submit
3. AngularJS intercepts data, processes payment and sends requests to server.

This is where controller receives transaction confirmation details from my PHP:

```
this.stripeResponseHandler = function (status, response) {
...
$http ({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://server/billpay/charge.php',
        data: postData  
}).then (function (response) {
        console.log (response.data);
        that.result = response.data;
        that.isSaving=1;
}, function (response) {
        console.log ("failed %s", response);
        that.isSaving=1;
})
```

**Problem:**

I need to replace entire existing page (with the form) to the full HTML page (with CSS, HTML, JS) returned by the server.

Server returns the receipt which user can just print for the records.

Essentially I don't want to just inject server's response to DIV (or similar) on the current page, instead entire new page needs to be re-rendered from the server response.

How would I do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: You can do it, but doesn't sound like the good idea. Consider redirect to new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do:

```
document.open()
document.write(that.result);
document.close();
```

But that's somehow "self erasing code": Your script is gone after the `close`;

Comment: Actually this works pretty good! It is exactly want I want to do as - render a single page printable receipt.

Answer (score 1):

create another page with (CSS, HTML, JS) and after form submission redirect to that page with server response data.

Comment: How do I redirect in Angular to another page, when HTML for this page is held in a variable?